# Why are prime numbers formally defined with the clause "two smaller positive integers" and not "aside from 1 and itself"?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, definition

Wikipedia (similarly to a textbook I have) defines a prime number as a **natural number "greater than 1 [that] cannot be written as the product of two smaller natural numbers"**.

The phrase **"the product of two smaller natural numbers"** seems to me to mean the same as **"the product of two natural numbers that are not 1 or the number itself"**. Why the former and not the latter? Typing it out, I just realized that the latter is much longer (especially if you, as I'm thinking would be necessary, assign "the number itself" a variable). Is this the only reason? Or am I missing something such that the phrase I suggested doesn't mean the same thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are often multiple equivalent definitions one could give for any particular concept.  In such cases, it is rare that one definition is clearly superior to another, and so any may be used.  This is the case here: both definitions describe exactly the same numbers, and it doesn't take much work to see that they describe the same numbers, so either can be used as the definition.  It is a matter of taste, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

They do mean the same thing.

Actually, your version is better! -- for generalizations where there may not be an ordering of the numbers into "smaller" and "larger" such as the [Gaussian integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integer) $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-1}]$.

Comment: But if you're in a ring, you need to differentiate between irreducible elements (if you write it as a product, one factor is a unit) and prime (if p divides ab, the p divides either a or b), and so this isn't actually the right generalization.

Comment: Good point @Aaron but still it's a right generalization, even if not the only generalization.